# Edit credit memo

Tags: orders, creditmemo, backorder, edit-order

I made a misstake in a credit memo.
I needed to add some additional cost, but forgot that.

How can I remove or edit the creditmemo?

Someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento doesn't provide such feature as remove/edit credit memo
If you return money to the customer - you can't gain it back.

Comment: So there is no solution for this problem?

Comment: No valid solution I think. Sure nothing is impossible, but looking for hack is not good idea, I think.

Comment: Who voted -1 please explain